# Calling Status Bar notification from method from other class

Tags: java, android

Firstly, I am new to both android and Java.

I have two classes, my main.class and Note.class.

I am calling the notification method from my Note.class in my main.class when i press a button.

The issue is with this line from the Note.class :

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
```

When the method is called it force closes. I believe the problem to be with the "this" in PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);, but I am unsure what to change it to.

The notification code works fine if it's in the main class.

I would be very grateful for any guidance.

**Edit:**
Main class : http://pastebin.com/05Yx0a48

Note.class :

```
package com.adamblanchard.remindme.com.adamblanchard;

import com.adamblanchard.remindme.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;



public class Note extends Activity {

public CharSequence note = "not changed";
int HELLO_ID = 1;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setTitle("Remind Me!");


}

//Notification Method

public void callNotification() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    final NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

    int icon = R.drawable.launcher;
    CharSequence tickerText = "Remind Me!";
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    final Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

final Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence contentTitle = "Remind Me!";
CharSequence contentText = note;

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, AndroidNotifications.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);





        mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);

        HELLO_ID++;
}

 }
```

Debug Output :

> Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception IllegalStateException))
>       Note(Activity).getSystemService(String) line: 3536
>       Note.callNotification() line: 37
>       remindme$1$1.onClick(DialogInterface, int) line: 72 
>       AlertDialog(AlertController$ButtonHandler).handleMessage(Message) line: 159 
>       AlertController$ButtonHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99
>       Looper.loop() line: 123 
>       ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3647
>       Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]
>       Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507
>       ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 839
>       ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 597 
>       NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]

This is the debug output I get, plus a force close popup on the device.

**Edit2:**

Manifest xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.adamblanchard.remindme"
  android:versionCode="3"
  android:versionName="0.7">
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher72">

<activity android:name=".com.adamblanchard.remindme" android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".Note">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="Note" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>


<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="1"></uses-sdk>
</manifest>
```

Stack traces (Are these what you mean?):

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception ActivityNotFoundException)) 
Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(int, Object) line: 1404    
Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Context, IBinder, IBinder, Activity, Intent, int) line: 1378  
remindme(Activity).startActivityForResult(Intent, int) line: 2827   
remindme(Activity).startActivity(Intent) line: 2933 
remindme$1$1.onClick(DialogInterface, int) line: 82 
AlertDialog(AlertController$ButtonHandler).handleMessage(Message) line: 159 
AlertController$ButtonHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99    
Looper.loop() line: 123 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3647    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 839  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 597 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

or:

```
01-15 00:56:18.167: WARN/dalvikvm(14887): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-15 00:56:18.217: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14887): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 00:56:18.217: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14887): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.adamblanchard.remindme/com.adamblanchard.remindme.com.adamblanchard.Note}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
01-15 00:56:18.217: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14887):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
01-15 00:56:18.217: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14887):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
01-15 00:56:18.217: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14887):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
01-15 00:56:18.217: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14887):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
01-15 00:56:18.217: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14887):     at com.adamblanchard.remindme.com.adamblanchard.remindme$1$1.onClick(remindme.java:82)
01-15 00:56:18.217: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14887):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
01-15 00:56:18.217: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14887):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-15 00:56:18.217: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14887):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-15 00:56:18.217: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14887):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
01-15 00:56:18.217: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14887):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 00:56:18.217: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14887):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-15 00:56:18.217: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14887):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-15 00:56:18.217: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14887):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-15 00:56:18.217: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14887):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-15 00:56:18.237: WARN/ActivityManager(156):   Force finishing activity com.adamblanchard.remindme/.com.adamblanchard.remindme
01-15 00:56:18.747: WARN/ActivityManager(156): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{40a15868 com.adamblanchard.remindme/.com.adamblanchard.remindme}
01-15 00:56:18.777: DEBUG/Launcher(10740): -- loadPreferences()
01-15 00:56:19.177: INFO/ActivityManager(156): No longer want com.facebook.katana (pid 14395): hidden #16
01-15 00:56:29.177: WARN/ActivityManager(156): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{40a15868 com.adamblanchard.remindme/.com.adamblanchard.remindme}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code from your Note class?  Also, please show us the details of the error message you receive.

Comment: Are "main" and "Note" both activities? Posting more details will help us answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK! I fixed it!

In the manifest.xml I needed to use the full name for the activity, ie:

```
<activity android:name=".com.adamblanchard.Note"></activity>
```

I have been messing around with the code, so other things may have contributed, but as soon as I changed this it worked.

Comment: You should change the name of the package for your Activities (in your Java code) to just com.adamblanchard instead of  com.adamblanchard.remindme.com.adamblanchard .  The latter does not make sense as a package name.

Comment: Done. I'm not sure how that happened.

Answer (score 0):

In your remindme activity, you have the following line:
 `Note Note = new Note();`

This is **not the correct** way to instantiate an `Activity`.  You should create an `Intent`:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Note.class);
```

and pass it to `startActivity`.

Comment: I have tried using 
              Intent myIntent = new Intent(remindme.this, Note.class);
              remindme.this.startActivity(myIntent); 

when the button is pressed, but i still get force closes.

I believe i need to declare the intent in the androidmanifest, but i am unsure what to put.

Thankyou for your help.

Comment: You need to declare ALL of your Activities in your manifest.  For example:  <activity android:name=".Note" />

Comment: That's what I have in there at the minute and I'm still getting force closes on button press.

Comment: Post your entire manifest.xml.  Also post the stack traces for the exceptions you are getting, which should be in your LogCat window.